# Will master branch have changes if I will push my new created branch(see details)?

Tags: git, gitbucket

I was working on some quick update ticket. We decided to do this in master branch and push code directly to repository. But I end up doing more than quick update and we realize that this will effect many places. I have committed my code to master branch locally while working on update. And now, we decided that we cannot push this code directly to master because we end up not having enough time to test. We will create separate branch and push this branch with this changes and after release will merge them and do our testing.

My question - if I will create new branch from my current master branch and will push that new branch, will this effect our master branch or not? (because I have committed to the master branch locally)

I'm going to follow this steps:

```
git branch upgrade_branch
git checkout upgrade_branch
git add (all upgrade work)
git commit -m "upgrade for xxxx"
git checkout master
git push origin upgrade_branch
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you avoid asking the upstream (`origin`) Git repository to update its `master`, you will be fine.  The steps you have outlined should work well.  You might, however, want to adjust your own `master` branch name back once you have created the new branch, just so that you *can't* ask the `origin` repository to adjust its `master`.

This particular sequence:

> ```
> git branch upgrade_branch
> git checkout upgrade_branch
> ```

can be shortened to:

```
git checkout -b upgrade_branch
```

You can then do your add and commit as you outlined.  After you do:

> ```
> git checkout master
> ```

though, you can run `git status`.  If this says that your `master` is ahead of `origin/master`, you can use `git reset --hard origin/master` to rewind your own `master` back to the same commit as identified by your `origin/master`.  That will mean that even if you accidentally run `git push origin master`, nothing will happen.

If your `push.default` is set to `simple` (this is the usual case), you will need to use:

```
git push -u origin upgrade_branch
```

initially to create the new branch `upgrade_branch` on the Git over at `origin`.

Note: the way to understand this is that every Git has *its own* branch names.  Your branch names need not be the same as theirs.  Normally, you will use the same branch names that they will, because it's very confusing to remember that your branch name `fred` corresponds to their branch `wilma`, your `barney` goes with their `betty`, and so on—but in *principle*, at least, your names and their names are entirely different.  So even if you've changed your `master` around, that has no effect on *their* `master` unless and until you have your Git call up their Git and *ask them to change theirs*.

This is what `git push` is about: your Git calls up some other Git, gives them new commits if needed, and then *asks or tells them to change some of their names*.  The names you ask or tell them to change are up to you, at `git push` time, and `git push origin update_branch` asks them to change (or create) their name `update_branch` based on your name `update_branch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Super clear explanation and just completed this steps - all looks good!